Story that includes imagined music instruments appearing in a room
I'm trying to remember/find out which (older) sci-fi book or short story has a section where the author describes entering a room and an imaginary electronic musical instrument or instruments appear to take form, possibly emerging out of the material that makes the room's floor and walls. A kind of synthetic metamorphosis that reshapes the surface material.
I read this a long time ago and just cannot recall. Searching has proved fruitless. A longshot is that it might be a scene in a "Dumarest saga" book, but that's probably unlikely (but is possible).

I have read the first 15 Dumarest books, and I don't remember anything like that in any of them. Could be in a lter one, though.

Near the end of Fred Hoyle's fragmented time and music novel 'October the first is too late', the 'explorers' live in a future society with blank rooms, where food, furniture and a piano appear from the fabric of the building.
It is an odd, but memorable, scene in a curious book.
